# I can't delete a file in Java (Windows 7)

Tags: java, windows-7

I have some trouble deleting a file in Windows 7, using this code :

```
    private static final String WIN_DIR_TEST = "D:"+File.separator+"Users"+File.separator+"u119255"+File.separator+"Desktop"+File.separator; 
    ...
    File file = null;
    FileWriter fileWriter = null;
    String localPath = WIN_DIR_TEST.concat("abc.degno");
    file = new File(localPath);
    fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
    fileWriter.write("qwertyuiop\n");
    fileWriter.close();
    ftp.send(localPath, distantPath);
    file.delete();
```

And this last line always return false, and I don't understand why. Also, no exception occurs.

Comment: did you check the permission and who has access to delete the file ? also check the path too.

Comment: If this is Java 7, ditch `File`, use `Files`.

Comment: Looking at that code it looks like the File variable is never set to anything but null?

Comment: The file is still `Null`

Comment: Some clarification : I am using Java 6 (and can't switch to 7), and I need the code to also work on SunOS

Comment: What is ftp object ? It probably reads the file without closing it. Check ftp send method implementation for stream leaks ...

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the exception handling like this:

```
try {
    if (file.delete()) {
        System.out.println(file.getName() + " is deleted!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Delete operation is failed.");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java has often Problems to write to Files which lies directly in C: Hard Disk (or the Disk where Win is installed).
Move the File to a subfolder on C:.

Comment: Move e.g. C:/test.txt File to C:/TestDirectory/test.txt

Comment: My file is written on D:\u119255\Desktop

Answer (score 1):

Try using `file.deleteOnExit()` instead of `file.delete()`

If that works maybe there's something in your code that still has a handle on the file.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, because as I can see from your code the "file" is always equals null :) Where do you initialize you file variable?

Comment: `file` cannot be null because, if it would be, then a `NullPointerException` should be thrown.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the line where file is instanciated

Comment: Yes, it must return NullPointerException, but we don't see the whole code. I suppose that code is surrounded with try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues deleted with deleting a folder containing other files.

So I ended up with deleting recursively the folder.

```
    private void deletedFile(File file)
{
    if ( file.isFile() )
    {
        file.delete();
    }
    else
    {
        File[] subFiles = file.listFiles();

        for ( File subFile : subFiles )
        {
            deletedFile(subFile);
        }
        file.delete();
    }
}
```